# Appears the world more reddish due to our vitreous body in our eyes?

Tags: electromagnetism

Our vitreous body in our eye consist mostly of water. The refractive index of water is 1.33. If ligth is refracted the frequency stays the same but the wavelength will get shorter to equal to the speed of light in water of 225.000km/s.

Does this mean that the blue color which is from 476-495 nm outside our eyes would be 30% longer in our eye that will give 620-643 and that is closer to the red color. Is this true or did I forget something?

Answer (score 1):

The wavelength should indeed be reduced. However, the eye works in a complicated way, the whole notion of color depends on the whole biology of it. From a physics point of view, it is just a different wavelength.

The eye does not have a wavelength scale attached to it, so it is just a question of gauging the eye. And that has been done by the evolution.

As far as I understood the eye works by having a chemical split by the photons. That effect will only depend on the energy of the photons and not on the wavelength. Therefore the water in the eye should not alter the energy of the light and therefore not change what kind of chemical reactions the photon can kick off.

Either way, a constant redshift would have been adapted away by evolution. Also one should ask why the visible spectrum is just the one that we do see, why not more IR or UV?